# Speed up search in column

Tags: vba, search, vlookup

In order to find specific values in a column and use the corresponding value in the next column, I use code below. Although it works perfectly, I am looking for a faster way to do this search.

However, the column I want to search is increasing in size as you can see in the first part of the code.

This works fast enough for columnsizes up to a few hundred values, but when it has more then 20000 values it is really slowing down. Since I have to do this some ten times in my userform I would like to do this a lot faster.

```
Public Function LR3() As Long   'Func.loc. HW08
    Worksheets("Sheetname").Activate
    Application.Volatile
    LR3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

For i = 1 To LR3
    If CStr(Sheet11.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value) = FunctionalLocation.Value Then
        Description.Value = Sheet11.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
    Else
         'no action
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Why do you implement such a basic feature as searching yourself? Maybe you should try to use the built-in functions like `VLOOKUP` or a combination of `MATCH` and `INDEX`. Does it have to be a macro? Is your data sorted (or sortable)?

Comment: I agree with @Conrad: sounds like you can do this with built-in Excel functions. Not clear why you go down this convoluted VBA path. If you want help, please show some example input and output.

Comment: I am a comment  and I agree with the two comments above me.

Comment: @Conrad-That is exactly why I asked this question.I am a noob and this is what I thought would do the trick. If there is a better way, please tell me how can I find it with Google.

Comment: @ Jean-François-Yes, I think so too, but I could not find anything usefull, because I can't find the correct search arguments. I don't need a solution as that will only help me how to solve this particular problem. All I need is a place to start, e.g. the right search arguments. Anyway thanks for the input everybody.

Answer (score 0):

use dictionary, try this

```
Sub test()
Dim Dic As Object, key As Variant, LR3&, oCell As Range
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
LR3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For Each oCell In Sheet11.Range("A1:A" & LR3)
    If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
        Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, 1).Value
    End If
Next
For Each key In Dic
    If key = FunctionalLocation.Value Then Description.Value = Dic(key)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try to implement it and come back with result

Answer (score -1):

I assume the 2nd codefragment is copied out of a larger Sub, if so, it would be helpful to know what "FunctionalLocation" and "Description" are exactly.

But I guess this is what you want:

```
Sheet11.Description.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2:B" & LR3 + 1 & ",2,false)"

Sheet11.Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & LR3 + 1 & ""), Type:=xlLinearTrend
```

Comment: This is part of a userform which will be used to enter data to a database-like sheet which will be used for analizing maintenanceplans. FunctionalLocation is a partcode called KKS-code for use in powerplants and description is the partname. I have seen your approach several times, but could not find the right syntax. I hope this will help me find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe to explain this further:

This just puts a VLOOKUP formula which gives you exactly the value you are looking for with your algorithm. The formula is put into the first cell and then autofilled until the last one. It should be way faster than looping through every single cell. If you need help to do this in a more dynamic way, I'm happy to help. (:

Comment: Sorry for long time to react. I've been ill. Thanks everybody.